# Removing added layer using leaflet and Cartodb

Tags: leaflet, carto

I've added a layer to a map via Leaflet. It's actually a circle around a point. This gets added perfectly. I'd like for it to be removed when I click a certain button. Here's how I'm creating the circle. I'm adding it to a group, as there are instances where there are multiple circles and I'd like to remove them all at once.

```
    var five_mile = L.circle([latitude,longitude], 11046,{
    fillColor:'#1d5492',
  fillOpacity:'0.3',
  stroke:false,
  clickable:false
})
 map_object.addLayer(five_mile);
 assetLayerGroup.addLayer(five_mile);
 var layers = assetLayerGroup.getLayers();
  console.log(layers);
```

The console log shows me that there is layer data in the assetLayerGroup.

To remove the layer, I'm doing this:

```
$('#remove_cir').click(function() {
  assetLayerGroup.clearLayers();
});
```

`#remove_cir` is the ID for the button I click to remove the circles in the group. There are no errors thrown when I click this, but the circle isn't removed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you are adding the layer twice, once directly to the map (if that's what `map_object` is), and then again to the layer group.

This should work:

```
$('#remove_cir').click(function() {
    assetLayerGroup.eachLayer(function(layer) { map_object.removeLayer(layer) });
    assetLayerGroup.clearLayers();
});
```

But it would be better to add your layer and layergroup to the map in a different way.

```
// on instantiation add it to the map as an empty layer group
assetLayerGroup = L.layerGroup([]).addTo(map_object); 

// then add layers to the layer group, but not to the map
// with this, clear layers should work on the layer group as you have above
assetLayerGroup.addLayer(five_mile);
```